# Probability, Ball Box

Tags: probability

Boxes
Two boxes are given. There are 15 white and 12 black balls in the first box, and 14 white
and 18 black balls in the second box. Anna provides the following experiment. Anna takes
at once two balls from the first box and places them in the second box. Then, she takes one
ball wihout looking from the second box.

**Knowing that she took a black ball from the second box, what is the probability that
she transferred two balls of different colors from the first box to the second box?**

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and to explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).   This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Say event $A$ is two balls of different colours are transferred and event $B$ is that black ball is drawn from box 2 and use Bayes' Theorem.

For $P(A)$, remember that total number of outcomes is $\displaystyle{27 \choose 2}$ and $15\times 12$ possibilities for two different colours. For $P(B)$, compute it according to the data before the transfer was made.